# Elasticsearch multi_match scoring

Tags: elasticsearch

I was wondering if this is possible in ES:

Let's say we have text documents with name: Black Lion,Big Blue Lion, Lion and we do a multi_match query against these field with the search query "Lion". Right now it returns these 3 results as they match but in the following order:

Lion - score 4.1
Black Lion - score 3.9
Big blue Lion - score 3.7

It seems that the score is ranked by exact match > match in shortest sentence.

Is there any way where I don't care what the length of the value inside the "name" field and return something like:

Lion - score 4.1
Black Lion - score 4.1
Big blue Lion - score 4.1

I've tried using different type of multi_match but it's not used for this.

Comment: why do you want this? what's the point of having the same score for all documents?